# Why doesn't C return an error when I use a large int

Tags: c, overflow

Hello I am learning C and I believe I made a mistake in declaring 
`signed int testing=4294967295;` I didn't think this would work because while I know I could create an unsigned int of that size I thought that the range of a signed int was -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, therefore I expected an overflow error but I didn't get one. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`signed int` overflow results in undefined behavior. Compiler may or may not produce any warning or error.

#### C11: 3.4.3 (p3):

> An example of undeﬁned behavior is the behavior on integer overﬂow

Comment: Should also note that it is strongly recommended to always compile with warnings enabled (such as `-Wall` in GCC or CLang; `-Wextra` provides even more warnings, but I would **not** recommend the latter). Warnings would probably have caught such a problem at compile-time (even though the compiler is not *required* to, most do).

Comment: It isn't UB as there is no overflow (in the sense of the C standard), just an implementation-defined conversion from `long` (or whatever type the constant has) to `int` (or an implementation-defined signal is raised).

Comment: @Tim , Why is it that you do **not** recommend the latter(`-Wextra`)?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Overly verbose, with a *LOT* of false positives. For example, warnings about unused function parameters (which might be unused because of API, say, callbacks with an unused `userdata` pointer) or warnings about missing field initializers (when you're *intentionally* initializing a structure with `{ 0 }`, making the compiler zero-initialize everything else automagically).

Comment: @Tim, I was quite surprised to see that `-Wextra` had some false positives. I tried googling it, but I've had no luck. So I've asked [a question on SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28381716/disadvantages-of-using-the-wextra-flag-when-compiling-in-gcc)

Comment: @CoolGuy: I won't answer there, as it already has plenty of answers; but I did comment on the question and the accepted answer. I know plenty of people agree with me on `-Wextra` (hint: there's a reason why it's not included in `-Wall`!), though apparently not as many on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Overflow is not an error. It is just a bahaviour of int. I guess that in your case when overflow has happened your int just have different value than the one you've set.

Try printing int value. Depending on your settings and hardware many things can happen, but you will see some strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard states:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

That means if you get an overflow, you're out of luck - no behavior of any kind guaranteed. Unsigned types are a special case, and never overflow .